# puppeteer Promise.allSettled(page.type()) doesn't work

Tags: puppeteer

```
Promise.allSettled([
      page.type("#email", id),
      page.type("#pass", pw)
    ]).catch((e) => console.error(e));
```

I expect all code is working, but only second code in array is working

```
await page.type("#email", id)
await page.type("#pass", pw)
```

is working

Comment: Your top code is asking Puppeteer to type two things at once. That won't work, so just use the bottom working code. What's the problem with that code? If you're concerned about speed, maybe the site you're working with will accept setting `.value` for these fields, although ideally you're caching the credentials with `userDataDir` so this seems like a micro optimization.